# Computed and Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have component with computed:

```
computed: {
 pages() {
  return Math.ceil(this.$store.state.filter.totalParts / 18);
 }
},
```

In **parent** i have axios with request:

```
  clearTimeout(this.filteredCategoriesTimer);
   this.filteredCategoriesTimer = setTimeout(() => {
   axios.get('/shop', {
      params: {
        page: 1,
        per_page: 18,
        part_category_tags: this.checkedCategories
      }
    }).then((response) => {
        this.$store.commit(
          'addTotalParts',
          response.data.totalParts
        );

     })
    }, 0);
```

and **store**:

```
addTotalParts(state, payload) {
  state.totalParts = payload;
},
```

I got error with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

What i need to change for correct error?

Comment: in parent component, in which method you have written your code. Like in which method you are firing this code.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your question, it prompted me to make the right decision. :)